# Trying to calculate $\operatorname{dim}H_1(RP^2$#$T^2;Q)$ and $\operatorname{dim}H_1(RP^2$#$T^2;F_2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I am trying to calculate $\operatorname{dim}H_1(RP^2$#$T^2;Q)$ and $\operatorname{dim}H_1(RP^2$#$T^2;F_2)$

I know that $RP^2$#$T^2$~$RP^2$#$K^2$ and that $X(M$#$N)$=$X(M)+X(N) -2$ where X is the Euler Characteristic but not sure how to do the calculation.

Note $T^2$ is torus and $K^2$ is klein bottle amd $RP^2$ is real projective plane

Comment: What is the fundamental group? And how $\mathbb Q$ coefficient and $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficient acts?

Comment: The fundamental group would be $Z^2$ and $Z_2$ for the Torus and real plane respectively. Could you please explain how I can utilise this information? @Anubhav.K

Comment: See my answer..

Comment: There was a typo in my solution @ForTheGlory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X= \mathbb RP^2 \# T^2$. Now observe that $\pi_1(\mathbb RP^2 \# T^2)= <a,b,c| aba^{-1}b^{-1}=c^2>$. (you can easily prove this either by looking at the polygonal representation of the space, or by simply using Van-Kampen).

Now $H_1(X,\mathbb Z)= \frac{\pi_1(X)}{[\pi_1(X),\pi_1(X)]}$, i.e, abelianization  of $\pi_1$. So $H_1(X,\mathbb Z)= \mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z_2$.

Now if $F$ is a field then $H_*(X,F)= H_*(X,\mathbb Z)\otimes F$ (by universal co-efficient theorem for homology).

So $dim(H_1(X,\mathbb Q))= 2$ since tensor product with $\mathbb Q$ kills the torsion part. And $dim(H_1(X,F_2))=3$.